# Signalr CORS Requests

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core

I am using SignalR Server 3.0.0-alpha2 with vnext and am trying to figure out how allow all cors connections how do i do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is going to be handled by middleware that can be used in conjunction with any of the ASP.NET vNext frameworks (e.g. MVC and SignalR). Unfortunately, the middleware hasn't been implemented for vNext yet.

You can follow the progress on this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/498

Comment: What can I do in the mean time?